# Chrome extension pause until page loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that essentially interacts with a webpage, ie, filling in forms, selecting dropdowns, and clicking buttons. That's all fine and dandy, except that when a certain button is clicked, the page reloads. When this happens, I need my extension to wait for the reload to finish. I currently have this function in my background js file:

```
function checkLoaded (time) {
    console.log('Checking loaded...');
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
        if(changeInfo.status == 'complete'){
            console.log("Done");
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(checkLoaded, time, time);
    });
}
```

The expected outcome from calling `checkLoaded(500)` if that every 500 milsec, it will check  `changeInfo == 'complete'` if it is true, return out of the function as the page has completely loaded, if not, check again in 500 milsec. This is not working, and I need some help.

Comment: You might want to read about the setTimeout and setInterval Javascript functions.

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What's happening when you run that code?

Comment: @jadarnel27 In my workflow, this function gets called 4 times. In other words, I need to halt until the page has finished reloading, 4 different times. The call is made each time, I get `Checking loaded...` each time, but immediately after, the script continues on without any delay, once the page does infact finish loading, (<500 milsec later) I get `Done` printed in the console.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? What do you want to do after the page is fully loaded ? (I hope you have already looked `setTimeout()` up and know why it won't work in this situation.)

Comment: I think you might be approaching this incorrectly. You want to call `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` from a background or browser_action page then inject your script into the page using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.